# Model binding in ASP.NET Core to map underscores to title case property names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model class that I want to bind a query string to in my ASP.NET MVC Core (RC2) application.

I need to support underscores in query string keys to confirm to OAuth specs, but I want to work with title case property names in my application.

My model class looks like this:

```
class OauthParameters
{
    public string ClientId {get; set;}

    public string ResponseType {get; set;}

    public string RedirectUri {get; set;}
}
```

so I'd like to bind query strings like `client_id`, `response_type` and `redirect_uri` to it.

Is there a way for ASP.NET MVC Core to do this automagically or through an attribute annotation?

I've read some articles about writing custom model binders, but these seem to (1) be overly complex for what I'm trying to achieve and (2) are written for RC1 or earlier in mind and some of the syntax has changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Model binders don't have to be incredibly complicated, and they are definitely the right entry point for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html

Comment: But what's the problem, data view objects transformed (controller model) in  data transfer objects (Business Logic DTO) are common in mvc model biding don't see any problem with this approach

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the `FromQuery` attribute's `Name` property here.

Example:

```
public class OauthParameters
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "client_id")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [FromQuery(Name = "response_type")]
    public string ResponseType { get; set; }

    [FromQuery(Name = "redirect_uri")]
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for POST requests?

Comment: @dalemac Use [FromForm] instead of [FromQuery] for POST request.

Comment: For those looking for the json body solution: use e.g.
 [JsonProperty("json_name")]

Answer (score -2):

**Solution for .net core 2.1 and 2.2**

Or without attributes you can do something like this which is cleaner I think (of course if the model properties are same as query parameters).

Meanwhile I use it in .net core 2.1 and 2.2

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]ReportQueryModel queryModel) 
{ 

}
```