# Bind query parameters to a model in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am trying to use model binding from query parameters to an object for searching.

My search object is

```
[DataContract]
public class Criteria 
{
  [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

My controller has the following action

```
[Route("users")]
public class UserController : Controller 
{
  [HttpGet("search")]
  public IActionResult Search([FromQuery] Criteria criteria)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

When I call the endpoint as follows `.../users/search?first_name=dave` the criteria property on the controller action is null.
However, I can call the endpoint not as snake case `.../users/search?firstName=dave` and the criteria property contains the property value. In this case Model Binding has worked but not when I use snake_case.

How can I use snake_case with Model Binding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model binding in ASP.NET Core to map underscores to title case property names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305295/model-binding-in-asp-net-core-to-map-underscores-to-title-case-property-names)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to add `[FromQuery]` attribute to the model properties individually

```
public class Criteria
{
  [FromQuery(Name = "first_name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use data contracts with members with the custom names for GET and POST endpoints, so in the first case it will be FromQuery, and FromBody for POST request?

Comment: I can't get this to work but it is marked as an answer.

Comment: I just want to add that I had an issue which other people could encounter too: I named my parameter 'model'. My object had a property which was also named 'model'. The databinding wouldn't work untill I renamed my parameter.

Comment: `FromQuery` sits in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package, it is a bit sad to add this dependency to the project where you only store your POCO.

Comment: @sander 's solution worked for me - thank you I spend well over an hour trying to figure this one out. Lesson learned to check all parameter names.

Comment: @elembie yeah, this one was a real gotcha!

Answer (score 43):

**Solution for .net core 2.1, 2.2, 3.0 and 3.1**

Or without attributes you can do something like this which is cleaner I think (of course if the model properties are same as query parameters).

Meanwhile I use it in .net core 2.1, 2.2 and 3.0 preview & 3.1.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]ReportQueryModel queryModel) 
{ 

}
```

Comment: Yep, it works only with [FromQuery] in controller method

Comment: This is the correct answer for NetCore 2.1 and above, the accepted answer is an anachronism.

Comment: Either this should be the accepted answer or the OP which happens to be the one who's given the accepted answer should update their answer.

Comment: I think the problem is that this answer doesn't address the specifics of question. The OP specifically requires a different name for the property, and this doesn't support that, as stated by the person that gave this answer.

Comment: I'm using .net core 2.2 and this method doesn't work for me. However, the accepted answer does.

Comment: @TwistedWhisper I am still using it! Can be related to the binding. Are you sure you have same parameters in both side ( query string and class object ) ?

Comment: @TwistedWhisper It works fine for me. I am using it in .net core 2.2 and 3.0 preview 5 and 6. The secret is you have to have same spelling properties in both sides.

Comment: Make sure you're using Properties, in the Request model, and not fields. That was my missed mistake

Comment: @TwistedWhisper That's true. Same spelling!

Comment: @AlexGamezo That's true. It is important to use properties.

Comment: Yes, those should be properties with *getter* and *setter* and the class should have a parameterless constructor too

Answer (score 14):

For anyone that got here from search engine like me:

To make it work on asp.net core 3.1+

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] RequestDto request);

public class RequestDto
{
  [FromQuery(Name = "otherName")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Will read json property `otherName` into `RequestDto.Name` so basically you have to use `FromQuery` in 2 places.
Above answers are IMHO too complicated for such a simple thing already provided in asp.net framework.

Comment: It will also works with ```[JsonPropertyName("otherName")]``` on your properties. Because of that I´m assuming it will also work with Newtonsoft.JSON annotations (but didn´t try). So you can just specify ```[FromQuery]``` in your method and could still use the same object in a Body when needed (without additional annotations). No need to be this specific about it.

Comment: @Max - hi Max. No it doesn't work for Newtonsoft [JsonPropery(Name = "otherName")]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had an issue where my parameter name was `option` and in my class I also had the property called `option` so it was collapsing.

```
public class Content
{
    
    public string Option { get; set; }
    
    public int Page { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> SendContent([FromQuery] Content option)
```

changed the parameter to something else:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendContent([FromQuery] Content contentOptions)
```

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 6, I needed to add `[FromQuery]` to the endpoint's parameter, *as well as* add `[FromQuery(Name="")]` to each of the model's properties.

Rather than add the MVC dependency to my model project, I turned the service model into an interface and made a new model in the WebAPI project, which can use the annotations and implement the interface, so I don't need to create/map 2 models.

Answer (score 1):

According to [@Carl Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040492/carl-thomas) answer, here is the easier and the strongly typed way to have snake case FromQuery name:

**CustomFromQuery**

```
public class CustomFromQueryAttribute : FromQueryAttribute
{
    public CustomFromQuery(string name)
    {
        Name = name.ToSnakeCase();
    }
}
```

**StringExtensions**

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
  public static string ToSnakeCase(this string o) => Regex.Replace(o, @"(\w)([A-Z])", "$1_$2").ToLower();
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class Criteria
{
   [CustomFromQuery(nameof(FirstName))]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is going on in .NET 8 or if it is just my setup but I can't get `[FromQuery]` to work like @emery-noel said in his answer or any other answer for that matter.

Example, this will not work:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Agreements([FromQuery] ClientDocumentsParamsDTO parameters) { ...etc... }
```

`[AsParameters]` doesn't work either.  My only option is to either do something ugly like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Agreements(
    [FromQuery(Name = "organizationid")] int OrganizationId,
    [FromQuery(Name = "account-class-id")] int? AccountClassId,
    [FromQuery(Name = "account-preference-id")] int? AccountPreferenceId,
    [FromQuery(Name = "account-category-id")] int? AccountCategoryId,
    [FromQuery(Name = "account-type-id")] int? AccountTypeId
    )
{ 
 ... etc...
```

or something like this I'm guessing, which I haven't tried:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Agreements(){
  string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["fullname"];
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with [THIS](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42438) issue but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If the
`public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] RequestDto request);`

not work for anyone, you can try **[FromRoute]**

`public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] RequestDto request);`.

In your dto you must keep the [FromQuery]

```
public class RequestDto
{
  [FromQuery(Name = "otherName")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```