# Converting a POCO object with JsonPropertyName decorations into a URL query string

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

Is there an .NET API to convert a POCO object with `JsonPropertyName` decorations into a properly encoded URL query string?

For example, for:

```cs
public record AuthEndPointArgs
{
    [JsonPropertyName("response_type")]
    public string? ResponseType { get; set; } // "code"

    [JsonPropertyName("client_id")]
    public string? ClientId { get; set; } // "a:b"

    // ...
}
```

I expect: `?response_type=code&client_id=a%3Ab`.

A home-grown version I'm using for now:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a shallow POCO object into query string,
    /// with JsonPropertyName decorations becoming query string argument names
    /// </summary>
    public static string ConvertObjectToQueryString(object source, string query)
    {
        var uriArgs = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);

        var jsonNode = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(source) ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode));

        foreach (var item in jsonNode.AsObject())
        {
            uriArgs[item.Key] = item.Value?.ToString() ?? String.Empty;
        }

        return uriArgs.ToString() ?? String.Empty;
    }
```

**Updated**, for completeness, a reverse conversion:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a query string into a POCO object with string properties,
    /// decorated with JsonPropertyName attributes
    /// </summary>
    public static T ConvertQueryStringToObject<T>(string query)
    {
        var args = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
        var jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        foreach (var key in args.Keys.Cast<string>())
        {
            jsonObject.Add(key, JsonValue.Create(args[key]));
        }
        return jsonObject.Deserialize<T>() ?? 
            throw new InvalidOperationException(typeof(T).Name);
    }
```

Comment: I would override the ToString() method and return your "home grown" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no native .NET API, it seems like ASP.NET (Core) has support for reading it to some extent though (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42929376/9363973) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47931625/9363973)) but I can't tell how to create one.

The laziest solution would probably be to just serialize your object to JSON, and then `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(json)`, then pass that to a query param, which would like so:

```
&payload=%7B%22response_type%22%3A%20%22code%22%2C%22client_id%22%3A%20%22a%3Ab%22%7D
```

At the other end just `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthEndPointArgs>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(payload))` like [so](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2MgAPl). This is assuming you can edit both ends.

While it sounds kinda stupid, it works, at in certain terms may even be better than serializing your `AuthEndPointArgs` to a query string directly, because the standard for a query string lacks some definitions, like how to deal with arrays, also complex options. It seems like the JS and PHP community have unofficial standards, but they require a manual implementation on both ends. So we'll also need to roll our own "standard" and implementation, unless we say that we can only serialize an object that fulfils the following criteria:

- No complex objects as properties
- No lists/ arrays as properties

**Side note:** URLs have a maximum length depending on a lot of factors, and by sending complex objects via query parameters you may go above that limit pretty fast, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/9363973) for more on this topic. It may just be best to hardcode something like `ToQueryParams` like Ady suggested in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72168475/9363973)

If we do want a generic implementation that aligns with those criteria, our implementation is actually quite simple:

```cs
public static class QueryStringSerializer
{
    public static string Serialize(object source)
    {
        var props = source.GetType().GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public
        );

        var output = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            // You might want to extend this check, things like 'Guid'
            // serialize nicely to a query string but aren't primitive types
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var value = prop.GetValue(source);
                if (value is null)
                    continue;

                output.Append($"{GetNameFromMember(prop)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value.ToString())}");
            }
            else
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}

private static string GetNameFromMember(MemberInfo prop)
{
    string propName;

    // You could also implement a 'QueryStringPropertyNameAttribute'
    // if you want to be able to override the name given, for this you can basically copy the JSON attribute
    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Attributes/JsonPropertyNameAttribute.cs
    if (Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(JsonPropertyNameAttribute)))
    {
        var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(JsonPropertyNameAttribute)) as JsonPropertyNameAttribute;
        // This check is technically unnecessary, but VS wouldn't shut up
        if (attribute is null)
            propName = prop.Name;
        else
            propName = attribute.Name;
    }
    else
        propName = prop.Name;

    return propName;
}
```

If we want to support objects with enumerables as properties or with "complex" objects as members we need to define how to serialize them, something like

```cs
class Foo
{
    public int[] Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

Could be serialized to

```
?numbers[]=1&numbers[]=2
```

Or to a 1 indexed "list"

```
?numbers[1]=1&numbers[2]=2
```

Or to a comma delimited list

```
?numbers=1,2
```

Or just multiple of one instance = enumerable

```
?numbers=1&numbers=2
```

And probably a lot more formats. But all of these are framework/ implementation specific of whatever is receiving these calls as there is no official standard, and the same goes for something like

```cs
class Foo
{
    public AuthEndPointArgs Args { get; set; }
}
```

Could be

```
?args.response_type=code&args.client_id=a%3Ab
```

And a bunch more different ways I can't be bothered to think off right now

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<T>` documented in [How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

```
class AuthEndpointMarshaller : JsonConverter<AuthEndPointArgs>
{
    public override AuthEndPointArgs? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //TODO check typeToConvert
        AuthEndPointArgs result = new();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            throw new JsonException();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return result;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                throw new JsonException();

            string ? propertyName = reader.GetString();
            reader.Read();
            string? propertyValue = reader.GetString();

            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "response_type":
                    result.ResponseType = propertyValue;
                    break;
                case "client_id":
                    result.ClientId = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(propertyValue);
                    break;
            }
        }
        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, AuthEndPointArgs value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        value.ClientId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value.ClientId);
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer,value);
    }
}
```

You then call it using

```
string ConvertShallowObjectToQueryStringAlternate(AuthEndPointArgs source)
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
        Converters =
        {
            new AuthEndpointMarshaller()
        }
    };

    var jsonNode = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(source, options) ??
        throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode));
    return jsonNode.ToString();
}
```

or if you are looking for a quick solution

```
public record AuthEndPointArgs
{
    // ...
    public string ToQueryParams()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder($"?response_type={ResponseType}&client_id={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClientId)}");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```